# Error in Spring boot Session with Redis - No qualifying bean of type [...SessionRepository]

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-session

I'm following the official spring tutorial to add redis session support to spring boot.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/boot.html

**pom.xml**

```
    ...
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    ...
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
    ... 
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-redis</artifactId>
    ...
```

*I didn't add the version to spring sessions as from `1.3.0.RELEASE` of spring boot, the jar is included into it. Even adding the version `1.0.2.RELEASE` as per the tutorial didn't solve my issue*

Please note with spring-boot `1.3.1.RELEASE`, the spring version used is `4.2.4.RELEASE`

**Configuration**

```
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class HttpSessionConfig {
}
```

**Properties file**

```
#redis
spring.redis.host=127.0.0.1
spring.redis.port=6379
```

*I didn't add secret as my redis server password is empty. Even adding the password didn't solve my issue.*

When I run the application it gives the following error

> Caused by: ..NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [...SessionRepository] found for dependency: expect...endency. Dependency annotations: {}

**I have also added the full error stack for the reference below**

```
016-01-05 01:49:50.775 ERROR 7616 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    ...
    at com.enbiso.proj.estudo.Application.main(Application.java:25) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:99) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    ...
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springSessionRepositoryFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.session.SessionRepository]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.session.SessionRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.session.SessionRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:464) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ...
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.session.SessionRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ...
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

Comment: post the file which the beans

Comment: I didnt get you. Which bean file do you want? With related to Redis I havn't created any beans. Did I miss anything here?

Comment: Where is define this bean SessionRepository

Comment: Its not defined anywhere in my code. According to the spring boot isn't it suppose to get initiated by the framework itself?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the create a RedisConnectionFactory step.

Try this :

```
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class HttpSessionConfig {
        @Bean
        public JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
                return new JedisConnectionFactory(); 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are the steps I've followed to fix this problem:

1 - application.properties:

```
spring.session.store-type=redis
spring.redis.host=localhost
spring.redis.password=Password123OrSomething
spring.redis.port=1234
```

2 - pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

3 - Redis Configuration Class (Spring Boot):

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "spring.session.store-type", havingValue = "redis")
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class RedisSessionConfig {

  @Value("${spring.session.store-type}")
  private String sessionStoreType;

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RedisSessionConfig.class);

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    LOGGER.info("spring.session.store-type=none turns spring session off.");
    LOGGER.info("Redis Session Replication is turned {}.", sessionStoreType.equals("redis") ? "ON"
        : "OFF");
  }

  @Bean
  public ConfigureRedisAction configureRedisAction() {
    LOGGER.info("Preventing auto-configuration in secured environments.");
    return ConfigureRedisAction.NO_OP;
  }
}
```